# XNA - How to make an image disappear after x seconds?

Tags: image, xna, disposing

Sorry to bother everyone, I can't find any good tutorials on XNA so I just come here for help, so how do you make it wait before disposing?

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        mBatch.Begin();
        mBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height), Color.White);
        //How to make it wait for 3 seconds before disposing?
        mBatch.Dispose();
        mBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use elapsed time so after the application has been open for X seconds it will disapear

```
if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds <= 3)
{
    mBatch.Begin();
    mBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, 
        new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height),
        Color.White);
    //How to make it wait for 3 seconds before disposing?
    mBatch.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches based on what you are expecting to get.
If you want to have smooth fade-out effect, you can use the Color parameter to achieve transparency:
`mBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height), new Color(new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f - (currentTime / totalTime))));`
*currentTime* holds your current time, and *totalTime* is the time when you want the image to fully disappear.

If you need to do this kinds of animations more than one time, I recommend you to create a Timer class, which can help you navigating your time spans easily.